# Updating always encrypted column using synonyms

Tags: azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I have the following scenario where I have to update 2 always encrypted columns in a SQL Server stored procedure.

1. One column is in the current database (insert statement)
2. The other column is in another database which is being accessed by a synonym (update statement)

The always encrypted columns' master key is in Azure Keyvault.

The stored procedure is compiling successfully with either insert or the update, but not both.

When I include both the statements in the stored procedure, it fails with the error message:

> Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@variableName'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEKName', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DBName') and the expression near line '8' expects it to be DETERMINISTIC, or PLAINTEXT.

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserCreatedSPName]
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table(columns list)
    VALUES (incoming params)            
    
    UPDATE SynonymTable  
    SET AlwaysEncryptedColumn = [@sameincomingvariable as in above insert]
    WHERE [filter condition]
END
```

Is this something that can be accomplished?

I have tried moving the update statement into a separate stored procedure and calling it from the main stored procedure - but I am still getting the same error.

**Update**: The Insert and Update are both happening the same Stored procedure. Also the 2 tables have a separate Column Master Keys in Azure key vault

Answer (score 0):

I created a table and inserted values into that table and enable always encrypted column in by saving the master key value in azure key vault.
Table before encryption:

[image]

After encryption:

[image]

I created synonym table for the above table in another database using below code:

```
CREATE SYNONYM syn_product
FOR [product].[dbo].[DBtable]
GO
select * from syn_product
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I try to insert values into DBtable which is encrypted by creating stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[product]
   @id int, 
   @name VARCHAR(20), 
   @price int 
AS 
BEGIN 
   INSERT dbo.DBtable(ID,Name,Price) SELECT @id, @name, @price;
END
```

Executed the stored procedure.

```
EXEC  dbo.product @id = 6, @name = 'P6', @price = 100
```

I got below the below error:

[image]

I tried to update the column by using synonym table with below code:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[upda]
@id INT, @name VARCHAR (20)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE DBtable
    SET    ID = @id
    WHERE  name = @name;
END
```

Executed the stored procedure.

```
EXEC upda @id = 6, @name = 'P1'
```

I got the below error:

[image]

I disconnected the server and connected again with

```
Column Encrypted Setting = Enabled
```

in additional connection parameters.
Image for reference:

[image]

I selected Query Options:

[image]

From Advanced -> Check the box ‘Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted’

[image]

I tried to insert values in DBTable which in current database using below code:

```
 declare @id int = 12
declare @Name varchar(20) = 'P6'
declare @price int = 100
insert into DBtable values(@id,@name,@price)
```

It worked successfully,
Image for reference:

[image]

Data of DBtable:

[image]

I tried to update the Synonym table using below code:

```
declare @id int = 6
update syn_product set ID = @id where Name = 'P1'
```

It worked successfully.
Image fore reference:

[image]

Synonym Table data:

[image]

In this way we can modify the data in table which is having always encrypted column and its synonym table.

```
Note: SSMS 17.0 and above has the option to edit the Always Encrypted Column. You can get SSMS 17.1 from [here  ![Jump](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-sitefiles/10_5F00_external.png "This link is external to TechNet Wiki. It will open in a new window.")](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) .
```

Comment: Apologies if my original question was not clear. Individual Insert and Updates are working. But when they are both done in the same stored procedure thats when the error shows up. Also the 2 tables are having a separate Column Master Key in Azure KV.

Added this note in the main question as Update

Comment: check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/42c3ced6-04ab-45f2-a3af-39a3aa63e898/always-encrypted-columns-with-stored-procedure-for-insert-update-and-delete-using-ssms-for-testing?forum=sqlsecurity) once.